# Using Gitlab through SSH-tunnel

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

The situation:

I am working from machine1, where I have root access. From machine1 I can access machine2 (where I am a user with no privileges) through ssh.
machine3 (also user with no privileges) is not directly accessible from machine1. I need to use an ssh connection from machine2 to access machine3.
In short: machine1 can ssh into machine2 but not into machine3. machine2 can ssh into machine3.

I want to use gitlab on machine3, but I can't. If I try to clone my repository, I have this:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /path/nameOfRepository/.git/
ssh: gitlab.lmps.ru: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Actually, if I try to ping google.com on machine3 I have this:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

So, there is probably no internet connection on machine3. But I have internet connection on machine2, but there is no git on machine2.

I want to use git (clone and push to gitlab) on machine3 through machine2 which has an internet connection.

There are a lot of manuals about the same problem, but I am a beginner SSH and linux user and can't deal with it.

Finally: I have a repository on gitlab and want use it on machine3 through machine2.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Install a proxy for example apache squid on machine 2, run it on an open port which is 3128 default, make some configuration on conf file for example write machine 3 ip as accepting source.

Go to machine 3 and set proxy address of machine 2 with its port. For example setting http_proxy and https_proxy env variables.

This is a sample possible concept to solve your problem if you don't have other restrictions. If you have questions just Google around this concept.